# How to send fb app invites like Kiwi App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I got a app invite on fb from a friend via [Kiwi app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chatous.pointblank).

[image]

When I clicked this notification it redirected me to their Google Play Store app page.
I downloaded it and signed up with facebook giving basic info, friend list and email address permissions.

When I logged in, the first screen I get to see is the one below. It is an 'invite your friends' page but what amuses me is that it does not show a fb invite dialog as mentioned in [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android). The official docs does not mention any method to build your own custom UI.

So how does Kiwi manage to build a custom UI, load all my friends(all 2000+) and ask me to invite them all. There is not even a limit of max 50 requests.

I want to implement this in my app as well. Please can anyone post a snippet for this.

[image]

Comment: Please check this developer page for app invites: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android

Comment: @DaminiMehra This is not the app I am taking about.
See Kiwi App here - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chatous.pointblank

Comment: which app you have to use fro app invite?

Comment: I have already referred to developer docs, also mentioned it in my ques. Please read ques properly.

Comment: then what is your problem.if you refer this docs then it is easy to implement app invites

Comment: if you want to fetch all friends from facebook then you have to take permission from facebook using fb sdk you can fetch all friends in array and make it custom @Timmy Simons

Comment: @DaminiMehra If you follow official docs, fb takes control by showing you their own dialog and asks user to select their friends for invite. I want to change 2 things. (A) I want my own custom UI like Kiwi did and (B) I want to preselect all friends and provide a deselect option so that user can willing deselect specific friends.

Comment: Perhaps they are using the invitable_friends - but that is only allowed for game apps that have an actual implementation of the game on canvas.

Comment: _"and (B) I want to preselect all friends and provide a deselect option so that user can willing deselect specific friends"_ - that is still a very spammy thing to do. You should rather encourage the user to explicitly select friends they think might enjoy your app as well, instead of pressuring them into needlessly spamming all their friends.

Comment: @CBroe I checked that too. Kiwi is also an app on fb but not a game.

Comment: @CBroe It's not spammy because I will provide a 'Unselect All' button as well. [see screenshot]

Comment: That's a bogus argument. You are still initially suggesting to the user that just blindly spamming invites to all their friends was o.k. and a normal thing to do.

Comment: @CBroe That is a different discussion altogether. Leave that aside. 
Can someone just explain how Kiwi is doing something that Facebook does not provide a method for.

Comment: @TimmySimons better to show some part of the code.

Comment: Hello @TimmySimons have you find? because I am also looking for same as KIWI app request features in my app, can you please help me if you already done with the same ?

Comment: @TimmySimons , I search the solution too

Answer (score 0):

To create custom invites like the Kiwi app your app should be a game, and use Game requests to invite friends

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests